# Sync Google Account programmatically without going through the setup screen

Tags: java, android, api, gmail, provisioning

I have a scenario where I have a server that holds username/password. So upon launching my android app and the user it authenticated I would like to automatically sync his account (Gmail for example) without going through the traditional setup screen.Are there any public googe/gmail APIs that I could use for this purpose. Any help at this point would be greatly appreciated.